# Building RPM to install .desktop file that contains MimeType

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build RPM to install .desktop file that contains MimeType, because .desktop file contains MimeType it needs update-desktop-database command to take effect after placing .desktop file in /usr/share/applications, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by adding the following part after %install:

```
%post
update-desktop-database
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing .desktop file is covered here:
  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Desktop_files

Updating mime database is covered here:
  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets#mimeinfo

Comment: Oddly, RedHat seems to have removed all information about MIME from the Fedora packaging guidelines (which themselves have been moved to https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/).  I went looking specifically for the section one MIME scriptlets today, having seen it before, but it's gone.

Comment: That is because as of Fedora 25+ this scriplet is not needed anymore https://web.archive.org/web/20170714013809/https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets because MIME use file triggers https://rpm.org/user_doc/file_triggers.html